# Permission denied error while installing MATLAB 2017 on ubuntu16.4

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install MATLAB 2017a the first I used ./install and got permission denied error the next made super user and that error repeated again.
This is whole of my installation process:

```
reza@reza:~$ cd /home/reza/Desktop/matlab-linux/1

reza@reza:~/Desktop/matlab-linux/1$ ./install
./install: 1: exec: /home/reza/Desktop/matlab-linux/1/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Permission denied

reza@reza:~/Desktop/matlab-linux/1$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for reza: 

root@reza:~/Desktop/matlab-linux/1# ./install
./install: 1: exec: /home/reza/Desktop/matlab-linux/1/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Permission denied
```

Please help?

Comment: This question doesn't belong to this community. Ask it in "Ask Ubuntu".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. It belongs in Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com

Comment: Maybe you need to 'chmod +x install' first.

Comment: I did .that not worked@tony_felloni

Answer (score 0):

The Matlab installation copies itself to `/tmp` and tries to run there.

Most likely `/tmp` is mounted in such a way that you are not allowed to run executables in it.
(Check with `mount | grep noexec`)

You probably have a line similar to `tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777 0 0` in your `/etc/fstab`.

Remove the `nosuid,nodev,noexec` part, remount `/tmp` *(or better: reboot)* and try again.

(After the installation you can restore the line in `/etc/fstab`)